# Nvidia driver breaks vncserver on CentOS 7.4, is there a work around?

Tags: centos7, vnc, nvidia

```
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
uname -r output: 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
NVidia driver: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.66.run
```

When using the Nvidia graphics card driver with the Nvidia GeForce GT 720 graphics card on CentOS 7.4 it works fine for the wired computer monitor on the console. However, when attempting to connect to the vncserver, you only get a blank black screen on connection. I have removed the Nvidia driver, and VNC works again. Apparently I just recently found out that the Nouveau driver works with VNC, but it doesn't with the wired computer monitor on the console.

Is there a work around for using the Nvidia driver and be able to get VNC to work? Possible configuration files changes or a simpler GUI to use with Gnome? Currently I'm using metacity in the ~user/.vnc/xstartup file. Or is there another good alternative to using the vncserver/tigervnc?

Comment: What about SSH with X11 forwarding?

Comment: How would I set this up to try it?

Comment: Actually, I'm quite sure you're able to find out on your own, but as a starting point, have a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely), for example.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Control the :0 display of X with VNC (the one displayed on your monitor by default)? If you open a separate session (like :1), display driver should have nothing to do with VNC, because in this case VNC works as a virtual X display, thus no driver is needed. Is this a solution for you?

Comment: I'm trying to use this system with the Nvidia driver installed to be accessible by VNC. If I remove the Nvidia driver, then VNC works. With the Nvidia driver installed and working for the wired console, VNC just gets a blank black screen.

Comment: @Edward_178118 Is this also true when you run a command like this: 'vncserver :1' from terminal and connect to the new session?

Comment: Yes, still get a blank black screen via VNC.

Answer (score 2):

[TurboVNC](https://turbovnc.org/) + [VirtualGL](https://www.virtualgl.org/) is a good alternative.

Pros:

- [Good](http://theterminallife.com/virtualgl-on-centos-7-using-nvidia-tesla-gpus/) performance.
- Works with desktop environments, that require 3D acceleration ([like Gnome3](https://askubuntu.com/a/53023/92948)), with `-3dwm`.
- Remote 3D rendering works [even with headless GPUs](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/HeadlessNV).

The cons is that it might be tricky to config. I've just finished setting it up on my CentOS 7 and NVidia K80. I doubt my config is perfect, but here's a set of points I'd like to highlight:

1. Official guides ([1](https://turbovnc.org/Downloads/YUM),[2](https://virtualgl.org/Downloads/YUM),[3](https://turbovnc.org/Documentation/Documentation),[4](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/Documentation)) might look somewhat too long and scary at the first glance, but they are rather easy to follow. They do miss some important pieces of information, though ([1](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/RHEL6),[2](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/HeadlessNV),[3](https://github.com/TurboVNC/turbovnc/issues/65#issuecomment-247812349),[4](https://turbovnc.org/Documentation/Compatibility)).
2. I've used [kmod-nvidia](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kmod-nvidia) drivers from elrepo, blacklisting `nouveau` with [two lines](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/765530/cuda-setup-and-installation/unable-to-load-the-kernel-module-nvidia-ko-/post/4275320/#4275320) `echo -e "blacklist nouveau\noptions nouveau modeset=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf`, not with one single-line, like suggested in many other guides ([1](http://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/installing-nvidia-drivers-rhel-centos-7/),[2](https://linuxconfig.org/nvidia-geforce-driver-installation-on-centos-7-linux-64-bit)).
3. Checking the following logs is a good starting point, when something goes wrong: `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `~/.vnc/*.log`. Most error messages I ran into are already discussed and rather easy to google.
4. Pay attention to the `xdpyinfo -display :0` sanity check there. If it's not working, try answering `n`/`n`/`n` in `vglserver_config` and [disabling selinux](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtualgl/discussion/401860/thread/6f2e2505/#d80f). Also, personally, I ended up [replacing](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtualgl/discussion/401860/thread/6f2e2505/#7650) `gdm` with `lightdm`.
5. Although in general Gnome3 works OK, some weird errors do happen time-to-time (e.g. Firefox works, but opening downloaded archive with the built-in archive manager fails with an error like [this](https://github.com/VirtualGL/virtualgl/issues/14)). So, I ended up installing KDE Plasma, so that `-3dwm` is no longer needed. (But I still like TurboVNC server, cause it's fast).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding the root cause is NVIDIA installs its own GL libraries which break other X environments.

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/Xvnc | egrep GL
libGL.so.1 => /lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f7ed8f5b000)
```

A cheat is to jumper-out the NVIDIA libGL.so by directing vncserver to the /usr/lib64 BEFORE /usr/lib64/nvidia:

```
$ diff -cbtw /usr/bin/vncserver*
*** /usr/bin/vncserver  2018-12-08 11:07:14.871180204 -0500
--- /usr/bin/vncserver.rhel71   2014-03-10 12:17:32.000000000 -0400
***************
*** 216,223 ****

  # Now start the X VNC Server

! $cmd = "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; ";
! $cmd .= $exedir."Xvnc :$displayNumber";
  $cmd .= " -desktop " . &quotedString($desktopName);
  $cmd .= " -httpd $vncJavaFiles" if ($vncJavaFiles);
  $cmd .= " -auth $xauthorityFile";
--- 216,222 ----

  # Now start the X VNC Server

! $cmd = $exedir."Xvnc :$displayNumber";
  $cmd .= " -desktop " . &quotedString($desktopName);
  $cmd .= " -httpd $vncJavaFiles" if ($vncJavaFiles);
  $cmd .= " -auth $xauthorityFile";
[merc_user@pair-1-host ~]$
```

This is working for me with Red Hat 7.1 and CUDA 9-2.

Answer (score 0):

To continue working around the NVIDIA vs native graphics problem with the NVIDIA libGL issue, I have made the following cheats:

```
$ mv /usr/sbin/gdm /usr/sbin/gdm.bin
$ mv /usr/bin/Xorg /usr/bin/Xorg.bin
$ # make edits - show results 
$ cat /usr/sbin/gdm
#!/bin/sh
#
# workaround for libGL issue
#

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

exec /usr/sbin/gdm.bin "$@"
$ cat /usr/bin/Xorg
#!/bin/sh
#
# workaround libGL issue
#

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

exec /usr/bin/Xorg.bin "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution on a fedora 29 machine. 
I believe this is a distribution independent issue.
Move or copy the distribution versions of libGL to /usr/local/vnclib:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/vnclib
total 596
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Feb 14 07:11 libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Feb 14 07:11 libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.7.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 610208 Feb 14 07:11 libGL.so.1.7.0
$

make a /usr/local/bin/vncserver:

$ cat /usr/local/bin/vncserver
#!/bin/bash
# added because nvidia driver overwrites these
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/vnclib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin/vncserver $*
```